# Increase Max # of user of hostednetwork

Tags: windows, windows-8, wireless-access-point, netsh

I've been playing with the hostednetwork feature of Netsh (windows), at the beginning I was able to have barely 100 users connected to the network, but for some reason now I can only have 7 users. There's any way to increase back again the maximum number of user (through command line or editing files)?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no way to increase it beyond 8 (including the hosting machine), as on Microsoft's website it stated that **Max 8 machines can be connected via SoftAP (Soft Access Point) mechanism**.

Comment: Would you mind linking to the page that states that?